# Copying char* with char symbol

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy a char* and char symbol into a new char* , however the desired result after copying is wrong.

```
char* name = "someData";
char symbol ='!';

int size1 = strlen(name);
int size2 = 1;
int newSize = size1 + size2 + 1;
char* res = new char[newSize];
strcpy(res,name);
const char* symbolPointer = &symbol;
strcat(res, symbolPointer);
cout<<*res;
```

I expect the result to be "someData!" , however it is only "s" , where is my mistake?

Comment: Deferencing `char*` only gives you the first char. Use `printf` or construct a `std::string`.

Comment: Your code has UB, `strcat` expects a null-terminated char*, which `symbolPointer` is not.

Comment: This code is so not C++. It is more like `C` with two C++ features. I is way easier to use `std::string` (and it would be faster).

Comment: @erip I would recommend against using `printf` in C++. It's difficult to use, especially by beginners.

Comment: @eerorika I'd recommend against using `char*` in C++, but here we are. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> char* name = "someData";
> ```

This is an ill-formed conversion in C++ (since C++11). I recommend to not point to string literals with pointer to non-const.

> ```
> const char* symbolPointer = &symbol;
> strcat(res, symbolPointer);
> ```

Both arguments of `std::strcat` must be null terminated. `symbolPointer` is not a pointer to a null terminated string. Because the pre-condition of `std::strcat` is violated, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
> cout<<*res;
> ```

`res` is a pointer to the first character of the string. By indirecting through the pointer to first character, you get the first character. That is why you see the first character (in case the undefined behaviour hasn't caused the program to do something completely different).

Lastly, the program leaks the allocated `res`.

---

Here is a fixed example:

```
std::string name = "someData";
name += '!';
std::cout << name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

```
cout<<*res;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
cout << res[0];
```

It prints just the first character of the output. Use

```
cout<<res;
```

Comment: That's true, but his code is buggy before that.  I don't know why you got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
const string name = "someData";
const char symbol ='!';

string res = name + symbol;
cout << res;
```

[You should **avoid**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rstr-string) the legacy C nul-terminated string handling functions.  [You should **avoid**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete) using `new` directly in your code.

The observed result you are asking about is due to you writing `*res` (a single character) instead of `res` (a pointer to the first character) in the output statement.  But the code was buggy besides that, as `strcat` will copy until it finds the terminator, so it will overwrite some unknown amount of memory beyond what you allocated.

Answer (score -5):

symbolPointer should end with null character, because strcat requires 0-terminated string.
So if you want to continue on your way,
(not a good idea but)

You can add this before strcat.

`*(symbolPointer+1) = 0;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char name[] = "someData";
    char symbol ='!';
    
    int size1 = strlen(name);
    int size2 = 1;
    int newSize = size1 + size2 + 1;
    char* res = new char[newSize];
    strcpy(res,name);
    char* symbolPointer = &symbol;
    *(symbolPointer + 1) = 0;
    strcat(res, symbolPointer);
    cout<<res;
    return 0; 
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: No, you cannot, as you clobbered something beyond the named variable.  Also, don't do things that the reviewers here **constantly tell posters not to do**, namely `using namespace std;`, or including the deprecated C headers.

Comment: which is deprecated header? I really didn't have idea

Comment: `symbolPointer` does not point to an array, and so `*(symbolPointer+1)` is invalid

Comment: Why did you add a screenshot to the same code you had above?  We normally don't advise posting pictures of code.  Read some of the current reviews that are tagged [C++] and you'll quickly see mentions of header files.

Comment: @DenisTurgenev `which is deprecated header?` The C standard library headers such as `<string.h>` are deprecated in C++. It is recommended to use `<cstring>` instead.

Comment: oh, thank you. though i am not c++ expert, I publish my answer, because I can learn more than i publish nothing. For example, I found that string.h is deprecated. if you want to learn swim, then should jump into water

Comment: @alterigel, this student seems to don't know about pointer concept, so I wrote that answer to explain how to control pointer. When we start learn c++, we don't care about security problems like memory overflow. It's a later problem after he improved himself to certain level. It was just my foolish thought, so don't angry at me. I think the main actor is questioner himself anyway.

Comment: @JDługosz, I am relatively new here, so didn't know about "using namespace std" issue. why it is discouraged? can you tell me or give me any url?

Comment: @eerorika, can you give me url where I can see all deprecated header list?

Comment: example here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196540/simple-bank-account-application-using-composition/196615#196615  I suggest reading through that (Code Review) stack exchange, for questions tagged [C++] to get a feel for the common review issues.

Comment: list of headers:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header   scroll half way down to see the "C headers".

Comment: Here's an article of mine that points out cppreference as an essential reference, along with a few others. You might want to look through that:  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5249485/The-Most-Essential-Cplusplus-Advice

Comment: @JDługosz, "Variables are not penguins huddling together to keep warm" interesting and meaningful. #define PORT 254   // replace with...
constexpr int PORT = 254; any reason there ??

Comment: @JDługosz, what is the philosophy behind "Don't Repeat Yourself"? I can't agree "Don't use new/delete". After all, thank you, I knew something new.

Comment: Why not use macros?  Start with https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es31-dont-use-macros-for-constants-or-functions

Comment: I totally understood why you said "avoid macro", 100% agree. Thank you!